# Can anyone identify this material? Having a hard time cutting it using a bi-metal hole saw

Tags: troubleshooting, materials

[image]My FIL gave it to me, said he found it in when he was cleanig out an old cabinet shop. It's a very hard composite material of some sort. Fine-grained and powdery when I drilled a hole in it, the "sawdust" smoldered as I was doing so. As you can see in the picture, it kind of chipped off where the drill came through the underside.

I am chewing up a 3-1/2" bi-metal hole saw attached to a Craftsman percussion drill, and not able to get through more than a couple of mm in before it slows the drill down.

Anyone know what this material is? Thinking I might just take it to a metal fabricator or someone with a router. However, I want to call and tell them what I've got before lugging it around.

Any advice on cutting it would also be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a concrete epoxy composite. I really don't know but it reminds me of manufactured stone.

Comment: Do you have the hammer on or off?  The hammer action won't work right with a hole saw.

Comment: possibly something like Corian .... it would help if you posted a clear picture